# Google Search Console: Separate Subdomain Property from Top Level Property

Tags: google-search-console

I'm working with a website and there's a subdomain which I don't have access to.

In Google Search Console, the "Property" consists of the entire domain, including this subdomain. (It's all part of 1 Property).

The subdomain is handled by a different part of the company -- and it has a bazillion issues which show up in Google Search Console for the domain as a whole.

I'd like to separate these two domains into two different Search Console properties so that the top level site doesn't "see" the errors from the subdomain. And I'd like the subdomain to be its own property in Search Console.

(Also I'm a little afraid that the poor quality subdomain may be impacting the search performance of the top level domain? I'm not sure about this).

**What I've done so far:**

I used "Add Property" to add the subdomain to Search Console. That part was easy enough.

Now I have a listing for the top level domain and the subdomain.

**What I want to do next**

Is there a way to tell Search Console to then 'ignore' the subdomain from the main, top-level Search Console property?

Effectively this would give me two totally different Search Console properties. One for the top-level (minus the subdomain) and one for the subdomain.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the main domain and each subdomain separately as URL prefix properties. Then you will have properties for each.

Comment: That won't solve his issue since the top-level domain property will still include the subdomain he wants to exclude.

Comment: In my experience a prefix property of `https://example.com` does not include data from `https://bad.example.com`.   Only if you create a domain property for `example.com` do you get the two mixed together.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller That does not appear to be the case.

Comment: I just checked my own site that has subdomains. The prefix based property does not see any data for the subdomains. Note that you can also register a sub folder with GSC to only see data about that.

Answer (score 1):

Go to google search console,choose your top level domain,click on search result tab
and after that click +new > page > URLs not containing

you can filter your top level domain data from sub domain data.
[image]